# Vue.js - Element UI - How to know the state of form validation

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using, `vue-js` and `element-ui`

I would like to check the state of the validation of a form without having to click on a `submit button`

#### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/nw8mw1s2/

#### Steps to reproduce

Click on each field

The verification is triggered with the blur

Start filling the different inputs

#### Question

How can I do so when the last input is validated,  `isFormValidated` turns to `true`.

In other words, how can I say "If there is no field with the state error, then turn `valudateState` to true"

#### Tips

I guess we can check the `validateState` of each `formItem` of the form. But I do not see how to do it concretely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new method (say `updateIsFormValidated`), and bind it to the native `focusout` event of the form:

```
<el-form :model="ruleForm2" @focusout.native="updateIsFormValidated" ...>
```

This method will fire each time any of the inputs in the form loses focus. It will attempt to check that each field in the form component has successfully been validated, firing each 100 milliseconds if the validation status of any of the form items is still pending:

```
updateIsFormValidated() {
  let fields = this.$refs.ruleForm2.fields;
  if (fields.find((f) => f.validateState === 'validating')) {
    setTimeout(() => { this.updateIsFormValidated() }, 100);
  } else {
    this.isFormValidated = fields.reduce((acc, f) => {
      let valid = (f.isRequired && f.validateState === 'success');
      let notErroring = (!f.isRequired && f.validateState !== 'error');
      return acc && (valid || notErroring);
    }, true);
  }
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nw8mw1s2/3/)

Comment: The solution does not work in the case one of the field is not mandatory or does not have any rules to be validated against https://jsfiddle.net/wwyxt8es/

Comment: You might want to change `let fields = this.$refs.ruleForm2.fields;` to `let mandatoryFields = this.$refs.informationTabForm.fields.filter((f) => f.isRequired === true);` Anyway, nice solution thanks

Comment: Also I can't find a good solution when a `clereable dropdown` is involved : https://jsfiddle.net/mab3q4f1/

Comment: @Leo Updated the `reduce` function to take the field's `required` property into account. Not sure about the dropdown component, Looks like it doesn't play nice with the form's native events. Maybe you'll have to just specify the `updateIsFormValidated` handler on one of that component's events.

Comment: I struggled for the same reason for `radio` It seems that the `validateState` is not updated before the `event` `change` is triggered. So to validate `select` you better use `visible-change` event while for a `radio`  it just does not work