# How to enable/disable submit button based on form validation state in Element UI?

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, element-ui, element-plus

Using element-ui, the form validation is pretty decent, so I was expecting it to be pretty straight-forward to "wire up" a variable that represents whether the form is valid to the "submit" button.

I can certainly write a validation function and attach it to appropriate events on every field, but that seems duplicative.

For example, each rule already has a trigger that tells it when to evaluate the rule (e.g. blur, change).  If I have to attach an event to each el-input that mirrors the same triggers, that feels fragile to me.

For example, these rules trigger on blur or change.

```
    rules: {
        username: [
            {
                required: true,
                message: "please enter user name",
                trigger: "blur"
            },
            {
                min: 3,
                max: 32,
                message: "length must be 3 to 32 characters",
                trigger: "blur"
            }
        ],
        password: [
            {
                required: true,
                message: "please enter password",
                trigger: "change"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to do this, uh, elegantly?

Comment: see https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#validation

Comment: I was hoping for something that takes advantage of the built-in validation in element-ui form components, which is based on "async-validator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I used the vue.js 'watch' facility to monitor the form data (the key being that 'deep' is set so it monitors the field values) and run a check on it, updating a variable that disables the submit button:

The data section contains my form model and the enable variable:

```
data() {
    return {
        loginForm: {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        },
        formValid: false,
        ...
```

Which is attached to the button:

```
<el-button @click="submit" type="primary" :disabled="!formValid">Log In</el-button>
```

And the validation code, which is very generic (and may be able to be moved to a plugin):

```
watch: {
  loginForm: {
    handler(){
      this.checkForm();
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
methods: {
    checkForm() {
        let fields = this.$refs.loginForm.fields;
        if (fields.find((f) => f.validateState === 'validating')) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.checkForm();
            }, 100);
        }
        this.$data.formValid = fields.every(f => {
            let valid = f.required && f.validateState === "success";
            let notErroring = !f.required && f.validateState !== "error";
            return valid || notErroring;
        }, true);
        console.log('valid:', this.$data.formValid);
    },
    ...
```

(got this last part from another very useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399041/vue-js-element-ui-how-to-know-the-state-of-form-validation).  It craftily handles the possibility of in-flight validation)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for Element Plus [2023] with the Vue Composition API;

Add state for form validity using the form item's prop name (same name you use for the rules);

```js
const formValidity = ref({
    oldPassword: false,
    newPassword: false,
    confirmPassword: false
});
```

Created a computed property which is based on these values;

```js
const formValid = computed(() => {
    return (
        formValidity.value.oldPassword &&
        formValidity.value.newPassword &&
        formValidity.value.confirmPassword
    );
});
```

Create a handler for the form's @validate period (this event is fired each time validation occurs);

```js
function validateHandler(propName, isValid) {
    formValidity.value[propName] = isValid;
}
```

Bind the handler with the "validate" event;

```html
<el-form
    :model="ruleForm"
    :rules="rules"
    ref="ruleFormRef"
    @validate="validateHandler"
>
```

Disable the button based on the computed property;

```html
<button
    :class="`${!formValid ? 'disabled' : ''}`"
    @click="submitForm()"
>
    Save
</button>
```

or

```html
<button
    :disabled="!formValid"
    @click="submitForm()"
>
    Save
</button>
```